# Nested If-Then-Else usage in DataStage

Tags: datastage

I am trying to write the following nested If-Then-else statements in Transformation Stage of DataStage but its giving me compilation error. Can anybody tell me is there any other way of doing this?

```
If IsNotNull(DSLink16.DECISION_ID) 
Then (
    If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 1 Then (
        If DSLink16.DECISION_CODE = 'ALOW' Then 'DENY'
        Else If DSLink16.DECISION_CODE = 'DENY' Then 'ALOW'
        Else If DSLink16.DECISION_CODE = 'NOIS' Then 'NOIS'
    )
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 2 Then 'DSMS'
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 3 Then (
        If APPELANT_CODE = 'CLMT' Then 'ALOW' Else 'DENY'
    )
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 4 Then (
        If APPELANT_CODE = 'CLMT' Then 'DENY' Else 'ALOW'
    )
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 5 Then DSLink16.DECISION_CODE
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 6 or DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 7 or DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 8 Then 'DENY'
)

Else (
    If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 1 Then 'DENY'
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 2 Then 'DENY'
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 3 Then 'ALOW'
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 4 Then 'DENY'
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 5 Then 'ALOW'
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 6 Then 'DENY'
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 7 Then 'DENY'
    Else If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 8 Then 'DENY'
)
```

Comment: As soon as I click Ok, It turns into red.

Comment: remove everything and add one if/else block back at the time. As soon as it turns red you know what is wrong. If you found it, let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears every If should have corresponding Else block associated with it. Following worked for me:

```
If IsNotNull(DSLink16.DECISION_ID) 
Then (
              If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 1 Then (
                                If DSLink16.DECISION_CODE = 'ALOW' Then 'DENY'
                               ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_CODE = 'DENY' Then 'ALOW'
                               ELSE 'NOIS' 
                )   ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 2 Then 'DSMS'   ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 3 Then (
                                If DSLink16.APPELANT_CODE = 'CLMT' then 'ALOW' Else 'DENY'
                )   ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 4 Then (
                                If DSLink16.APPELANT_CODE = 'CLMT' Then 'DENY' Else 'ALOW'
                )  ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 5 Then DSLink16.DECISION_CODE
              ELSE   'DENY' 
)

Else (
            If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 1 Then 'DENY' 
                ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 2 Then 'DENY' 
                ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 3 Then 'ALOW' 
                ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 4 Then 'DENY' 
                ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 5 Then 'ALOW' 
                ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 6 Then 'DENY' 
                ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 7 Then 'DENY' 
                ELSE If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 8 Then 'DENY'
                                                                ELSE 'DENY'                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `DECISION_RESULT` is integer of some kind the final block could be written:

```
If DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 3 Or DSLink16.DECISION_RESULT = 5
Then "ALOW" Else "DENY"
```